# Is $n^\frac{1}{10} \in O((\log n)^{10})$?

Tags: logarithms, asymptotics

This question came up in a recent discussion: is $n^\frac{1}{10} \in O((\log  n)^{10})$?

First time I've come across a power of a log in a long time, and as far as I recall, there are no identities for power of logs. Not sure how tackle this.

Comment: Try computing $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n^{1/10}}{\ln^{10}(n)}$

Answer (score 2):

Comparing $f(n)=n^{1/10}$ and $g(n)=(\log n)^{10}$ may be done more informally by studying what happens when you square $n$: $f$ is squared, while $g$ is multiplied by $1024$. Clearly $f$ will eventually overtake any constant multiple of $g$ by repeatedly squaring the argument.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
\frac{n^{1/10}}{(\log n)^{10}} = \left(\frac{n^{1/100}}{\log n}
\right)^{10}
$$

Answer (score 0):

From the usual limit $\dfrac{\log n}{n} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} 0$ you can get $\dfrac{(\log n)^a}{n^b} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} 0$ for any $a > 0$ and $b > 0$.

So you don't have $n^\frac{1}{10} \in O((\log(n)^{10})$ but on the contrary $(\log n)^{10} \in O(n^\frac{1}{10})$.

Comment: what property of limits to infinity gets you that it converges to $0$ for any $a >0 $ and $b > 0$?

Comment: Since $\dfrac{\log n}{n} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} 0$, one also has $\dfrac{\log \log n}{\log n} \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} 0$. Now $\dfrac{(\log n)^a}{n^b} = \exp\left(a \log\log n - b \log n\right) = \exp\left(\log n \left(a \dfrac{\log \log n}{\log n} - b\right)\right)$. Since  $a\dfrac{\log \log n}{\log n} - b \mathop{\longrightarrow}\limits_{n \rightarrow +\infty} -b$, the argument in the exponential tends to $-\infty$. I have to admit it was not totally direct ! But the limit is quite classical.

Comment: As a remark, the limit also holds for $a \leq 0$ but in this case it is trivial.